# How to troubleshoot the wordpress issue when the site is migrated from one host to another?

Tags: wordpress

My original website name was www.xxx.com. However, I am not using that anymore. I am now using raspberry pi as a web server. After migrating to new database and domain - www.xxx.blogsite.xyz, I see that my website is not getting launched. I don't even see the dashboard for myself. How can I debug or troubleshoot this. I see that my apache is running fine. Also, I have tried restarting it. I can't access myphpadmin using public address or hostname. However, I can use myphpadmin using local IP address. Is something wrong with my dynamic dns setting?

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed the "Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location" here:

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location

?